# Are there any special characters that I should not support in a password that requires special characters? (WebMatrix C#)

Tags: c#, validation, passwords, webmatrix

I have a password that requires special characters and was wondering if there were any special characters that I shouldn't support, such as "=" or "`" or ">", etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        if(c!='!' && c!='@' && c!='#' && c!='$' && c!='%' && c!='^' && c!='&' && c!='*' && c!='(' && c!=')' && c!='-' && c!='_' && c!='+' && c!='=' && c!='~')
        {
            Scount++;
            if(Scount >= password.Length)
            {
                errorMessage = "Your password must contain at least one special character.";
            }
        }
```

Ok, I guess I know I don't want to support angle brackets, but is there like a standard set of special characters that most sites support, or characters that I should definitely stay away from (besides angle brackets, those would probably trip up the WebMatrix validator in a lot of cases).

Please do not comment on the fact that I am not using a regular expression to check for patterns.  I know this and I do not care.  This was the first thing that worked for me, so that's what I'm going with.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You shouldn't not support any.  Your users should be able to enter a kilobyte of line noise and it should be valid.  *You shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text anyway* so you shouldn't even need to do any work to escape special characters.

Comment: nah, you can have this one for free.

Comment: @Wug but what about angle brackets? I am not going to support those cuz the validator will give YSOD.  I could request it unvalidated, but I do not want to do that and begin welcoming XSS attacks through the admin password field.

Comment: I guess there is one addendum: depending on where and how the password is to be used, it might be reasonable to restrict whitespace (space, tab, newline)

Comment: @Wug true... but I don't think that will trip anything up, I guess I should check to see :)

Comment: @Wug but what about angle brackets? I am not going to support those cuz the validator will give YSOD. I could request it unvalidated, but I do not want to do that and begin welcoming XSS attacks through the admin password field.

Comment: Unless you're going to be displaying the password in the page, you'll be fine.  Just clear the password field on every page load, it shouldn't be remembering people's passwords by itself anyway.  The work the validator does is probably only a best guess, if you're using it safely there is no reason to restrict <> from passwords.

Comment: Honestly, if putting a `<` in a password can cause problems for your site, then I think you have a bigger problem. You *should* be able to handle absolutely any character. The password is simply an opaque blob of bytes. If your site can't handle those special characters (including `<`), then I suspect it has deeper problems

Comment: @Wug It's not that it can't, its that I don't want it to request information from the form in an unvalidated manner. Otherwise I would just use Request.Unvalidated("someName");

I like the fact that it checks for potentially dangerous content.

Comment: @Wug Answer me this and I may understand what you mean (it is a question I have never gotten a straight answer to).  If I am not inserting user input into the page (like a blog, etc., where it needs to plot raw HTML) do I ever (ever) have to worry about XSS?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since I saw this excellent [cartoon](http://xkcd.com/936/) on XKCD on password strength, any site that forces me to use upper or lower case chars, numeric or alphabetic... well it makes me mad.
The only checking your site should do, should be checking for the length of the password.

If people want to enter 0bscur€ passwords fine, but don't force them to.

Comment: Man, sometimes, you have to, though. I am building a database with sensitive personal information for Persons Of Interest, and if I left it up to the users they would pick the password "password" or "123" or something stupid like that.  Then, since it is a web interface, anyone could potentially guess that and compromise the security of ALL information stored within.  Sometimes you have to (also only the admin accounts are forced to use special characters).

Comment: @VoidKing Yeah, I can see you having to stop people using "password", but I'd just make them have a password length of 10 or 12. They'll probably choose "passwordpassword" just to spite ya though.
Having to choose a password of length 10 (12) will probably annoy folks just as much more as a 6 (8) letter password with 1 numeric in it, but at least it'll be more secure.

Comment: Well, you see, the problem is I'm pretty much instructed too at this point.  Kind of out of my hands, now.  I'm told "do it", so... I do it.